# Access express application from middleware

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, node.js-connect

I have a middleware, I call it like this:

```
app.use(example({optiona:'abc'}));
```

I want to access the app from the middleware function, and do another app.use, something like this:

```
module.exports = function (options){
    app.use(...);
    return function(req, res, next)
        next();
}
```

I know the option to pass the app to the exports, but I want to do it without the option to pass it, or set it as global..

Comment: You have the `app` available inside [`req.app`](https://devdocs.io/express/index#req.app)

Comment: I want to set a middleware generally, not to set it ("app.use") on each request

Comment: Please read about how middlewares work: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: I know how it works. I want to access the app inside the use function, and declare multiple middlewares..

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking into Express Routers as an option ([read all about it](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)).

Essentially, you could keep your first piece the same:

```
app.use(example({optiona:'abc'}));
```

And then you can do the following in the function instead:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function(options) {
    // You can declare middleware specific to this router
    router.use(...);

    // You can declare routes specific to this router
    router.get("/foo", ...);
    router.all("/bar", ...);

    // Then just return the router at the end
    return router;
}
```

Routers allow you to set up "sub applications" with their own routes/middleware accordingly.